# Node.js user trying to upload and process files the vanilla way using regular javascript+html

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, file, upload

Up until now, all of my Node.js code had worked seamlessly for any javascript+HTML project I had been working on. As a result of this, I had developed an incorrect conception that there is a one-to-one correspondence between Node.js and vanilla Javascript+HTML. What shattered this conception was when I had tried to utilize Node's 'fs' module in a webpage in order to read and process files.

My Node way of uploading files was this:

```
var fs = require("fs");
function processFile(filePath){
  var fileText = fs.readFileSync(filePath) + '';
  var linesOfText = fileText.split("\n");
  return linesOfText;
}
```

This would allow me to read a file in as a stream, which I would immediately convert into an array, which I could then process in any way that I wanted.

However, I am facing troubles when trying to express things using the vanilla HTML+Javascript modality of file uploads. I am able to upload the files just fine, but I cannot process them.

```
<input type="file" id="myFile" multiple size="50" onchange="myFunction()">
<script>
function myFunction(){
  var text = document.getElementById("myFile");
  var textArray = text.split("/n");
}
</script>
TypeError: text.split is not a function. (In 'text.split("\n")', 'text.split' is undefined)
```

I guess one of the problems I am facing is that I don't know what type of data I am dealing with once I upload the files, whereas in Node.js I was able to process the files and convert to array/strings no problem.

Help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Nakul

Comment: Check out [`FileReader` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) and FYI browser doesn't have a filesystem (for obvious reasons).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the FileReader API to access the contents of the uploaded file in the browser:

```
      function myFunction() {
        var file = document.getElementById("myFile").files[0];
        if (file) {
          var reader = new FileReader();
          reader.readAsText(file, "UTF-8");
          reader.onload = (e) => {
            var text = e.target.result;
            var textArray = text.split("/n");
          };
          reader.onerror = (e) => {
            console.log("error reading file");
          };
        }
      }
```